# Listview Image loading

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have this lisview that has images on its items, and what I'm trying to do is to load images on items that are not visible to the screen.

For example the user stops on position 5 of the lisview, obcourse the image will be loaded on that position. What I want is to load the images on position 4 and 6 as well. Is this possibele in listview? Any suggestion will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: use lazy loading when you are loading imageviews.

Comment: take a look this library https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I already do lazy load and used Picasso as my library. I need to do the above algorithm to create an illusion to the user that the images are loading fast.

Comment: @Erick please see my answer , for fast load you can use memory cache or file cache

Comment: @Erick I edit my answer just now please see it ,

Answer (score 0):

Erick, please try these,

1. *you can use **lazyadapter** to load images*
2. *you can use **file cache** and **memory cache** to load images quickly*

for memory cache and file cache : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/1332870)

### other links

[link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

[link2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

[link3](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/)